# Material-UI use default value in conditional 'overrides'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there pretty way to change value in MUIs `override` only when condition is met? I want to left control to MUI when condition is not met.

I want something like this, but I do not know what to pun on place of `?defaultValue?` (I do not want to put static value there.):

```js
const customTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
      MuiTableCell: {
        root: {
          padding: condition ? "50px" : ?defaultValue?,
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

Comment: Should be fine to put `undefined` in place of `?defaultValue?`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell No that falls to 0 not to MUI default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one syntax that works. The important aspect is to avoid defining a `padding` entry within `root`. Alternatively you could use a similar approach to avoid defining the entire `root` entry for `MuiTableCell` depending on whether you have other overrides that you still need to do when the condition is false.

```
const customTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTableCell: {
      root: {
        ...(condition ? { padding: "50px" } : {})
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit theme condition]